How to to clear/delete all controls on a TWebGridPanel in TMS WEB Core?
I've got a TWebGridPanel component that I'm dynamically populating with rows and columns as well as controls within those rows and columns.
My issue is that I need to clear/delete/destroy all controls in the TWebGridPanel component before populating it.
Firstly, I am clearing the rows and columns using:
WebGridPanel.RowCollection.Clear;
WebGridPanel.ColumnCollection.Clear;

This hides the controls that were on them, but obviously they still exist somewhere in the background/memory.
I tried the following ways (Each line is a different way I tried) to clear/remove/delete them:
WebGridPanel.RemoveControls;

WebGridPanel.DestroyComponents;

WebGridPanel.ElementHandle.innerHTML := '';

WebGridPanel.ElementHandle.querySelector('table').innerHTML := '';

None of the above ways really worked perfectly for me, then I tried looping through each control individually and destroying them and that seemed to work.
Currently, I am doing this:
for I := WebGridPanel.ControlCount - 1 downto 0 do
  WebGridPanel.Controls[I].Destroy;

And it works, but is this the best way? Is it even the correct way? Sure it works, but I don't know if it's technically the correct way or not.

Currently, all my controls are normal Delphi components, but what if it's HTML elements in there instead of Delphi components? Will my code still work?
What about events attached to my controls and elements?
All this, I am unsure about.

There is nothing wrong by looping. Bottom line whatever approach will you use in the end the code will always end up looping though collection of controls and calling Destructor for each on of them.
In order to make your life a little simpler you could create on or more TObjectList and while dynamically creating your controls also add them to one of these Object Lists. Then as long as such object list have its OwnsObjects property set to True Deleting any object from this object list will automatically call the object Destructor. And yes you can call Ojbect List Clear method to delete all items at once.
So why would you go creating multiple object lists? Because then you can in a way group your controls into multiple groups (one object list per group) and thus give yourself ability to destroy only specific group of objects while leaving rest of them alone.
